# Comment box in check out with big cartel neat theme

Tags: cart, neat, bigcartel

I'm wondering if there is any way to add a comment box in the check out or cart section of the customization field with the Neat theme by Big Cartel?

Answer (score 0):

Right now there's not a way to customize the checkout process to include any additional fields, however Big Cartel's Seamless Checkout option (Stripe or PayPal Express) has a "Notes" section built-in at the bottom of the checkout page, or you can use PayPal's "Notes to seller" field if you're using PayPal standard.